# Font property CSS not functioning

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS, and the fonts aren't working in my style.css folder
I've tried multiple times on separate projects, and it didn't work there either
the code is here:

```css
    body {
    background: #808080;
    text-align: center;
    }
      #main {
        width: 1000px;
        height:800px;
        background:#808080;
        margin: 25px auto;
    }
    h1{
      color: #ffffff
      text-align: center;
      font: Nunito;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-indent: 48px;
    }
    hr{
      color:#ffffff
      width:auto;
    
    }
    p{
      font: Nunito;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-indent: 48px;
    }
    a{
      color:#ffffff;
    
    }
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `font-family` property.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

Comment: `font` is a short-hand property, but it must include size and family. So if you change your rules to `font: 16px Nunito;`, everything should work fine. See [the Syntax section of MDN's documentation of the `font` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you want to use `font-family: Nunito`, the `font` property is a shorthand of `font-style`, `font-variant`, `font-weight`, `font-size` and `font-family`. You can read more about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You must change **`font: Nunito;`** to **`font-family: Nunito;`**

> Here you can find examples ---->
> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
background: #808080;
text-align: center;
}
#main {
  width: 1000px;
  height:800px;
  background:#808080;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
h1{
  color: #ffffff
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-indent: 48px;
}
hr{
  color:#ffffff
  width:auto;

}
p{
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-indent: 48px;
}
a{
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In CSS, we use the "font-family" property to specify the font of a text.

 The font-family property should hold several font names as a "fallback" system,
 to ensure maximum compatibility between browsers/operating systems. Start with the
 font you want, and end with a generic family (to let the browser pick a similar 
 font in the generic family, if no other fonts are available). 
 The font names should be separated with comma.

Note: If the font name is more than one word, it must be in quotation marks, 


like: "Times New Roman".
```